# Can I use the @Version field to automatically check for concurrent modifications?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, locking

I've got an entity with an annotated `@Version` field.  I am trying to use this field to check for concurrent modifications to the entity while by front end is displaying the data.  However, this does not seem to be producing the desired effects.

```
@Entity
public class User
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String username;
  private String password;

  @Version
  @Column(name="version")
  private Integer version;
}
```

I'm asking the front end to send the `version` field back to the server when posting data.  On the server end, I am retrieving the entity from the DB using the PK, updating the version (along with other fields) with the posted value, and then having the entitymanager persist the entity.  I was hoping that it would automatically throw a StaleObject exception if the version has changed in the meantime, but it does nothing.

After further reading, it appears that I am not allowed to modify the version field programatically.
According to the JPA spec, the application is not allowed to modify the version field:

> **JPA 2.0 Final Spec, Section 3.4.2:**
>
> An entity may access the state of its version field or property or
>   export a method for use by the application to access the version, but
>   must not modify the version value. With the exception noted in section
>   4.10, only the persistence provider is permitted to set or update the value of the version attribute in the object.

Is my only choice at this point to manually check the posted data's version against the DB's version every time myself?  Is there not a way to have the JPA provider do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

why not use JPA EntityManager's merge method?

[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29)

this method will first fetch the entity to the persistent context and copy all the values from your entity (detached) to the persisted entity. when the transaction is flushed, JPA will check the version for you. if it's stale, an OptimisticLockException will be thrown. using this method, you don't need to check the version yourself

Comment: I've considered using that, but that means that the complete entity is being merged.  In order to do that, since I want to copy selective fields from the client, I have to first retrieve the entity from the db, detach it, and then merge it.  Which kind of defeats the purpose of JPA's "magic" of persistence of not needing to instruct it to persist it every time.  Although i'm not telling it to persist, merge is pretty much the same thing in this context.

Comment: Hi @EricB. if you just would like to persist some of the properties, you can fetch a persisted entity into your persist context and manually copy those properties into it. I think JPA will handle the left things (like the version ) for you when the transaction ends. Version is just one of the mechanisms to maintain the optimization lock (I heard some other persistent framework may use time stamp instead of version) so it's better to let the persistent framework to manage the optimization lock for you but not touch it directly.

Comment: Sure; however when you retrieve data and send it to the client, and the client takes time before it sends it back to you, you need to ensure that the data on the DB has not changed since.  So even though I can retrieve the row from the DB and update it directly (by copying fields into that entity), I have to first ensure that the version of the row being updated is the same that was returned by the client (ie: no one has modified the row in the meantime).  Hence the desired use of the `@Version` field.

Answer (score 0):

Actually

> Optimistic locking is a technique that is used to insure that updates
>   to the database data corresponding to the state of an entity are made
>   only when no intervening transaction has updated that data since the
>   entity state was read.

And the exception being thrown in case of this rule is broken is an OptimisticLockException.

Some of the consideration.

1. Your provider should support optimistic locking.
2. There are some method that you could call to enable this kind of locking.

   lock(java.lang.Object entity, LockModeType lockMode)

   find(java.lang.Class entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey, LockModeType lockMode)

   refresh(java.lang.Object entity, LockModeType lockMode)